# Rails lightweight/raw WebSockets

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a Rails app that I want to use for some WebSocket stuff without ActionCable imposing Rails specific client-side structure on a separate JS app as well as some inter-process/server overhead on the server for every message (Redis).

Id still like to use Rails for the server instances so can directly use `ActiveRecord` and other such Rails components, but is it possible to strip out the extra stuff (channels etc.) from ActionCable to just get plain messages?

And ideally some control over what instance the socket connects to (e.g. to use the chat room example, make everyone that joins a given room connects to the same Rails process, e.g. via a URL query parameter, and not a tonne of separate subdomains/"separate apps")?

Comment: Have you found a solution?